# How to replace string in matching directory names?

Tags: bash, replace

While refactoring my code I had to change some variable names from `components` to `materials`. But now I need a way to replace `components` to `materials` in all folder names that match.

Something that could take me from here

- `/available-components`
- `/furniture-components`
- `/raw-components`

To here

- `/available-materials`
- `/furniture-materials`
- `/raw-materials`

I would also like to know how I can exclude directories from being traversed, something like

`-exclude ./node_modules`

I was thinking a `Bash` script can do the job, but I have never touched a scripting language other than to run my C++ code or start a NodeJS server, so explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use in Bash SED (Use LEX) or in Windows REGEX to replace strings.  LEX and REGEX are very similar string manipulation functions.

Comment: Please focus the question on a single environment, so either bash, PowerShell or VSCode.  This makes it easier for others looking for answers. Otherwise we end up with a mixture of solutions for different environments which isn't helpful. Apart from that, this is a very generic question, so it has propably already been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the command looks alike:

```
find . ! -path "*node-modules*" -path "*-components" -exec rename 's/components/materials/' {} +
```

Explanation:

- `find .` finds directories and files in the current directory
- `! -path "*node-modules*" excludes anything containing node-modules
- `-path "*-components"` means that the end of the path is components, the idea is to not attempt renaming the same nonempty folder many times
- `-exec` specifies that we want to execute something on the result
- `rename 's/components/materials/` specifies what to replace and what to replace with in our collection